# Filter Real Values with Mathematica

Tags: filter, wolfram-mathematica

I am working with rather big matrices where I want to filter out the real values.

```
{999, "na", Times[w, 1], 2.5, Indeterminate, 6.0}
```

should become

```
{"na", "na", "na", 2.5, "na", 6.0}
```

It works with

```
AnyMatrix /. {_If -> "na", _Last -> "na", _Mean -> "na", _Plus -> 
   "na", _Round -> "na", _Times -> "na", _Integer -> 
   "na", _DirectedInfinity -> "na", Indeterminate -> "na"}
```

but that is probably not very time-efficient. Also, I cannot predict what
other non-real forms will show up in the future.

Is there a cleverer way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be efficient:

```
lst = {999, "na", Times[w, 1], 2.5, Indeterminate, 6.0};
pos = Position[lst, _Real];
ReplacePart[ConstantArray["na", Length[lst]], 
 Thread[Rule[Flatten[pos], Extract[lst, pos]]]]

(*=> {"na", "na", "na", 2.5, "na", 6.} *)
```

Even more efficient:

```
lst = {999, "na", Times[w, 1], 2.5, Indeterminate, 6.0};
pos = Position[lst, _Real];
SparseArray[Thread[Rule[Flatten[pos], Extract[lst, pos]]], 
  Length[lst], "na"] // Normal

(*=> {"na", "na", "na", 2.5, "na", 6.} *)
```

Another, simplified version (safer than previous attempts and also very efficient):

```
lst = {999, "na", Times[w, 1], 2.5, Indeterminate, 6.0};
Replace[lst, {x_Real :> x, x_ -> "na"}, {1}]

(*=> {"na", "na", "na", 2.5, "na", 6.} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc center tutorial *Finding Expressions That Match a Pattern* describes several ways to identify and select elements of a list.

Cases is one candidate function that will, in its simplest form, pick out and return elements of a list that match a pattern, here Real.

```
lst = {999, "na", Times[w, 1], 2.5, Indeterminate, 6.0};
Cases[lst,s_Real]

(* Out-> {2.5,6.} *)
```

But if you want to preserve the original structure of your data, then you will want to classify each element, keep it if it conforms, and replace it if it doesn't. You do this by supplying replacement rules to the Cases argument list, rules that can be constructed in the usual way with patterns, conditionals and computation. The following is a transparent way to do formulate a replacement rule that produces the desired result.

```
Cases[lst, s_ :> If[Head[s] === Real, s, "na"]]

(* Out -> {"na", "na", "na", 2.5, "na", 6.} *)
```

By default, Cases acts on the top level of a list - suitable in this case - but for more complex data structures, the level activity can be specified in the usual way.

Comment: Could you take a little time to explain what you have done here so that the OP and future generations of SO'ers will be able to learn from your post?

Comment: Flagged up.  This answer may be correct, but it needs to be fleshed out more.

Comment: @Fred - Your 2nd approach is ultra-speedy even on big level n matrices. I wonder why it functions because one should think that your coding also would replace the list heads so that I expected to see "na"["na",...,6.] ???

Comment: @Fred For nested lists I have to use: Clean[v_] := 
 With[{d = Reverse@Dimensions@v}, 
  Flatten[Fold[Partition, 
    Cases[Flatten@v, s_ :> If[Head@s === Real, s, "na"]], d], 1]]

Comment: @eldo - Cases defaults to Heads->False, so in the example, it skips over the List. Specifying

Comment: For inscrutable reasons, SO allows that comments can only be edited for 5 minutes, so I'm resubmitting my comment.

Comment: @eldo - Cases defaults to Heads->False, so in the example, it skips over the List. Changing that option to True yields {na, na, na na, 2.5, na, na, 6.}, prepending the extra 'na' in a flattened List.

Comment: @eldo - My approach to setting levelspec for Cases and for other Mma functions is purely empirical, so I can't offer any fundamental principles to guide preservation of the original data structure. What is clear, though, is that the default settings will flatten the result. Cases[{99, "na", Times[w,1], 2.5, {1.3, Indeterminate}, 6.0}, s_:>If[Head[s]===Real, s, "na"], Infinity] gives, {na, na, na, 2.5, 1.3, na, na, na, 6.}, so some kind of deconstruction or reordering will be necessary.